# php file to get device token and store it for later user

Tags: php, ios, iphone, push-notification

i v been looking through all sort of device token storing methods and i think my problem is where i send data from the iOS device.

for example

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myhost.com/filecreate.php?token=%@",
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"apnsToken"]]]; //set here your URL
```

what kind of php code should i write to handle something like that?

I m currently using xampp so i have it on my localhost.

i m a total newbie on php and decent iOS developer so i really don't know how to proceed.

this is how i edit 32 integer of device token

```
NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    //Format token as you need:
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
```

for pushing to php script

Comment: Can you give an example of the token you are pushing?

Comment: @DarylGill can you check again

Answer (score 0):

You are using a query string so you handle it like this:

```
$token = $_GET['token'];
```

I prefer post to do this:

```
$token = $_POST['token'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your IOS code you are using GET, by merely appending the parameter to the URL (Normal GET).
If you are using NSURLConnection,I will prefer the use of "GET " method by specifying the method as GET and not by merely appending the url.

You can do as follows,

```
   // Create the request.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myhost.com/filecreate.php"]];

// Specify that it will be a POST request
request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";

// This is how we set header fields
[request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
NSString *stringData = @"token=somedata&parameter_name=some_value";
NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

The method to get the value in php is

```
$token=$_GET["token"];
$second_param=$_GET["parameter_name"]; for GET method.
```

$_GET is a php Super Global used to manage GET requests.Like wise $_POST is used to  manage 'POST' requests.

To store the data, for a short term storage  you can use $_SESSION.

```
$_SESSION["token"]=$_POST["token"];
```

for long term storage use database of $FILE to create or write to file.

Reffer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)  to know more about Super globals like $_POST,$_SERVER,etc.